# Adding values to rows in CSV

Tags: beginner, csv, powershell

This code below is for one of my scripts that I am trying to automate. I am dealing with the rows and all the data that is in those rows. What I am trying to do is make this look neater and maybe adding some different variables to make it look decent.

```
Foreach ($row in $csv) {
If ($row.Type0 -eq 'Domain') { 
  $row."Unique Account Name" = "$($row.Domain0) - $($row.Account0)" 
If ($row."Unique Account Name" -in @('ACCOUNTS - DODSCAN'.'ACCOUNTS - Domain Admins','ACCOUNTS - LADM_WS_Admins','ACCOUNTS - Tech Enterprise'))
        {$row."Excluded" = "True"}
    Else {$row."Excluded" = "False"}        
 }
Else {
    $row."Unique Account Name" = "$($row.Netbios_name0) - $($row.Account0)"
    If ($row."Account0" -in @('esrxadm1n_esi','#Update','medco_tech','medco_admin'))
         {$row."Excluded" = "True"}
  Else {$row."Excluded" = "False"}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

- Indent the blocks properly.
- Define the immutable exclusion lists before the loop.
- To enhance readability, maintainability, and to avoid missing typos such as the dot after DODSCAN, which should be a comma, write just one array element per line without commas.

```
$excludedAccounts = @{
    unique = @(
        'ACCOUNTS - DODSCAN'
        'ACCOUNTS - Domain Admins'
        'ACCOUNTS - LADM_WS_Admins'
        'ACCOUNTS - Tech Enterprise'
    )
    account0 = @(
        'esrxadm1n_esi'
        '#Update'
        'medco_tech'
        'medco_admin'
    )
}

foreach ($row in $csv) {
    if ($row.Type0 -eq 'Domain') { 
        $newName = "$($row.Domain0) - $($row.Account0)" 
        $isRowExcluded = $newName -in $excludedAccounts.unique
    } else {
        $newName = "$($row.Netbios_name0) - $($row.Account0)"
        $isRowExcluded = $row.'Account0' -in $excludedAccounts.account0
    }
    $row.'Unique Account Name' = $newName
    $row.'Excluded' = [string]$isRowExcluded
}
```